# Mootools parents objekt change

Tags: object, background, mootools, parents

I'm looking for a solution for change CSS from a parent's object.

I have this:

```
<div class="layout">
   <div class="over"></div>
</div>
<div class="layout">
   <div class="over"></div>
</div>
<div class="layout">
   <div class="over"></div>
</div>
<div class="layout">
   <div class="over"></div>
</div>
<div class="layout">
   <div class="over"></div>
</div>
```

There are 6 Object like that on my site.
So what I want is when I use `mousenter` event on the DIV `over`
I want change `backgroundcolor` of the parent's "layout" not of every layout.

Nice would be if i can use `morph()` too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the parent element you use getParent function. if you wish to bind this to something different you can change the function to `function(e)` and then use `e.target`.

The reason to cancel the animation if it's running is to remove some ugliness when moving the mouse around a bit to fast. You can try to remove it.

```
$$('.over')
.addEvent('mouseenter', function(){
    var parent = this.getParent();
    var tween = parent.get('tween');
    if (tween && tween.isRunning()){
        tween.cancel();
    }
    parent.setStyle('background-color', '#f00');
})
.addEvent('mouseleave', function(){
    this.getParent().tween('background-color', '#fff');
});
```

Here is a fiddle with a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/vxQXU/1/